# Execute command line in attribute

Tags: templates, attributes, chef-infra, cookbook

I want to generate MAC address and UUID in attribute and then pass the values to template.
something like this :

`Attribute/default.rb`:

```
default['libvirt']['xml_mac_Adrr'] = 'openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/:$//''
default['libvirt']['xml_uuid'] = 'uuidgen virbr0'
```

`Template/network.erb`:

```
<uuid><%= node['libvirt']['xml_uuid'] %></uuid>
  <mac address='<%= node['libvirt']['xml_mac_Adrr']%>'/>
```

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**
I want to modify the `default.xml` network for the virtual network. Basically, we have to do it by `virsh-net command`
Now I want to use a template to pass UUID & MAC address values to XML file and modify it in guest machine.
this is my recipe:

```
template '/etc/libvirt/qemu/network/default.xml' do
 source 'qemu-network.erb'
 owner "root"
 group "root"
 mode "0644"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use backquotes to execute shell commands inside ruby and capture the response:

```
default['libvirt']['xml_mac_Adrr'] = `openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/:$//'`
default['libvirt']['xml_uuid'] = `uuidgen virbr0`
```

EDIT:

The second problem I see is that you have to use instance variables in the controller to share information with the view. So the best way would be:

```
@mac = `openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/:$//'`
@uuid = `uuidgen virbr0`
```

Then at view level you can use:

```
<uuid><%=@uuid %></uuid>
<mac address='<%=@mac %>'/>
```

Comment: Sadly chef attributes files doesn't cope well with backticks and the question was tagged RoR for no reasons.

Comment: acctualy I tried to modify default.xml for the virtual network. Your suggestion for the command was right. I don't have any error for running a default.rb. But I couldn't pass a value of the command to erb file. I will update my question with its recpie.

Answer (score 1):

Within chef relying on system commands should go through the [`shell_out`](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#shell-out) method (which is included in the recipe dsl) to avoid some quirks when the DSL interpreter is run and getting methosd to clean up the ouput.

I'd go this way:

```
default['libvirt']['xml_mac_Adrr'] = Chef::ShellOut.new("openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/:$//'").stdout.chomp
default['libvirt']['xml_uuid'] = Chef::ShellOut.new('uuidgen virbr0').stdout.chomp
```

But this has a problem, at each run, a new mac address will be generated, so you should use `normal` and avoid redefining it, this is easiest moved into the recipe, following in recipe file before your template code should do:

```
node.normal['libvirt']['xml_mac_Adrr'] = shell_out("openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/:$//'").stdout.chomp unless node['libvirt'].includes?('xml_mac_Adrr')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!